# handling slow internet connection in android

Tags: android

Am fetching JSON data from a remote server and before triggering the asynctask am checking for the availability of internet connection with the help of below code

```
    if (isOnline()==true){

        new DownloadJSON().execute();

    }
    //do whatever you want to do
    else
    {
        try {


            Toast.makeText(context, "Slow or No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }


 public boolean isOnline() {

    try {
       Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
        int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
        boolean reachable = (returnVal == 0);
        if (reachable) {


            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        p1.destroy();
    }

    return false;


}
```

This works fine for no internet connection. Even it works in cases like, there is wifi but no internet access. But the problem is it blacks out my activity if the internet connectivity is slow and gets force closed.

Please guide me how can I add a timeout value to isOnline() or is there any better way to handle such error in catch block

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [AsyncTask class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ? It won't block the UI thread.